# Is $Ae^x$ the only function that differentiates to itself?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I know that the answer to this is a certain, yes. That can be seen by solving the separable ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$. Despite this though I thought up this strange function and there would be many others like it which by construction appears to have this same property as $e^x$. Written out it is:

$$...+\frac{(-1)^m \cdot (2m)! \cdot x^{-m-\frac{1}{2}}}{2^{2m}\cdot m!}+...-\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot x^{-\frac{7}{2}}}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}+\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot x^{-5/2}}{2 \cdot 2} - \frac{1 \cdot x^{-3/2}}{2}+x^{-1/2}+\frac{2 \cdot x^{1/2}}{1} + \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot x^{3/2}}{1 \cdot 3}+\frac{2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot x^{5/2}}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}+...+\frac{2^{2n}\cdot n! \cdot x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{(2n)!}+...$$

There are some obvious issues with this function such as that it isn't even real for negative values of $x$. The positive powers of $x$ converge by the ratio test but I have my doubts for the negative powers and I think that is where the problem lies. I only have one term of analysis to grapple with this problem so I am unsure where to go with it now. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this is not a function. - Let $f$ be a fucntion with $f'=f$. Then $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$ defines a function with $g'(x)=-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}f'(x)=0$. I hope you at least do not doubt that the only functions with zero derivative (on a connected domain) are the constants

Comment: Yes, the negative parts of your power series do not converge.

Comment: Just to make your series a bit easier to understand, is it the case that you have a series of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nx^{n+1/2}$ with terms $a_n$ chosen so that the derivative of $a_nx^{n+1/2}$ is $a_{n-1}x^{n-1/2}$?

Comment: @ChenWang How would you go about showing this? I can get the intuitive sense from trying some values but I don't know how to show it formally.

Comment: @Arthur That is correct

Comment: The ratio test applies to the negative powers as well as to the positive.  As the coefficients are reciprocal, the convergence of the one implies the divergence of the other.

Comment: What about the (-1)^m though? I get that if it was a straight sum for the negative powers then the convergence of the positive would imply the divergence of the other but why don't the alternating signs mess up that reasoning?